# What Ruby on Rails plugin/gem would you recommend to implement widely-used blog publishing API (Atom, MetaWeblog, etc) in a custom blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a custom-made blog running off RoR and I would like to implement publishing API. I would prefer to use a widely-used API - e.g. Atom, MetaWeblog, etc - so that I can post to my blog from almost any other web service - flickr, youtube, pixelpipe, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the bloggity gem. I am starting to use it and it looks as though it has most of what you would want.

Comment: bloggity has way too many features that copy functionality I already have.